# JavaFX: GridPane align label to the right

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

For hours I'm trying to get this result: [Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTkpa.png), [GridDesign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW10b.png), [FinalResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiEhD.png)

My problem here is that I cant align properly the TotalPrice label, I want it to take 2 columns and align to the most right of the grid, when the label size gets bigger(More text is added to the label) I want it to grow only on the left side and still be aligned to the right of the grid!
But nothing seems to work properly!

In my case when I add a bigger price, it wont stay like I want to...

Here's my result with smaller label text, in this case it looks perfect, the price is aligned perfectly to the right:
[result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYi9d.png)

But here's the bad result when I put a bigger number, you can see the TotalPrice label is not aligned as it should:
[result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iYH5.png)

Here's my code with hardcoded strings just for testing:

```
GridPane grid = new GridPane();

//Delete Button
Button btn = new Button("X");
btn.setPrefWidth(40);
btn.setPrefHeight(40);

//Labels
Label productName = new Label("MaxiCheeseBurger Menu");
Label productPrice = new Label("120 den");
Label productQty = new Label("x1");
Label totalPrice = new Label("120 den");

totalPrice.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
totalPrice.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

//Styling labels
productName.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 14;" +
                     "-fx-font-weight: bold;" +
                     "-fx-text-fill: #707070;");
totalPrice.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 14;" +
                    "-fx-font-weight: bold");

//Setting grid column constraints
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ColumnConstraints col = new ColumnConstraints();
    col.setPercentWidth(100.0 / 5);
    col.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
    col.setFillWidth(true);
    grid.getColumnConstraints().add(col);
}

//Adding nodes to grid
grid.add(btn, 0, 0, 1, 2);
grid.add(productName, 1, 0, 4, 1);
grid.add(productPrice, 1, 1);
grid.add(productQty, 2, 1);
grid.add(totalPrice, 3, 1, 2, 1);

GridPane.setFillWidth(totalPrice, true);
GridPane.setHalignment(totalPrice, HPos.RIGHT);
grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);

grid.setHgap(3);

rows.getChildren().add(grid);
rows.setSpacing(5);
receipt_section.setContent(rows);
receipt_section.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5));
```

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).